# python script shows 100% cpu utilization after running in dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am dockerizing a python script, and I run it as `CMD ['python', 'script.py']`, in the Dockerfile. When I `up` the container using `docker-compose.yml`, it runs,

But when I `docker exec` and go inside the container and do a `ps -aux`, I see the %CPU is 100%, because of this the purpose of the service is not met.

If I do the same process, i.e, by doing a `docker exec` and run the script `python script.py` manually in the container, It works good and I can see only a 5% of the CPU is utilized, as well as the service works and gives the expected result.

Service wrote in docker-compose:

```
consumer:
    restart: always
    image: consumer:latest
    build: ./consumer
    ports:
      - "8283:8283"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST = redis


  redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - ./redis_data:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

It is a consumer application, which consumes the message from the producer and writes into a Redis server.

Can someone advice why such behavior is observed.

Comment: This is a 100% issue?

Comment: Yes! Looking for a helping hand.

Comment: No idea, if possbile a minimal example? Or some parameters different between `docker run xxx` V.S. `docker-compose.yaml` sections?

Comment: I have added a few more details to the question.